# Excel named range for subsets

Tags: excel

I have a sample table below:

```
Field1 Field2
A       1
A       2
B       3
B       4
C       5
C       6
```

(Note: lot more fields in full set).

Need to defined name ranges A, B, C so when I do validation it shows it’s subset.

I.e. A named range would result in choices 1 and 2. B named range would result in choices 3 and 4. Etc…

Right now I’m separated the table into individual lists to define the name range (I.e. column A has two values below it if 1 and 2). However this is an update nightmare when the original table has 60+ Names to map and gets updated weekly by multiple people.

Is there a way to automate from the main table to create all these named ranges and have the drop-down not show all the resulting blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do the following (with 3 helper columns):

1. Use a helper a column to extract the unique values in Field 1 and save this new information as a dynamic named range. To extract the unique values you can use the UNIQUE function (if your excel version has it) or the following array formula (don't forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works correctly):

   ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$100),0)),"")
   ```

Now you can create a data validation drop down just calling the named range as a list.

2. Use another helper column to extract the values in Field 2 taking the Field 1 value selected on the drop down list as an input.
3. Use an extra helper column to organize the data of the values in Step 2 and remove blanks. After that you can create a new dynamic named range and its corresponding drop down list.

Note: You can avoid the step 2 and 3 if your excel version has the FILTER function.

[You can find an example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19fIX8id_VjqZYlMI2TWVSerVwZIUMrQH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true) (download it as an excel file to test it)

Comment: This is great. How do you Adjust the helper columns if add more to the matrix? Like is there a way to adjust formulas in helper columns so they reference entire column versus cells X:Y.

Comment: @EricDavis you can change the references of the ranges to the entire column i.e. $A$2:$A$100 to $A:$A. However, in some cases this could make your file slow, so I recommend to use a "big" reference ($A$2:$A$5000) to the necesary rows instead of reference the entire column.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I'm set for 365 upgrade next month and that FILTER function will make it so much easier. That function will also help clean up some of my defined ranges on other workbooks that have blanks throughout reference souce.